# Win 8.1 and Win 10 - Do they really have Task Scheduler 2.0?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

On this page, I see that Task Scheduler 1.0 came out with Win 98 (unless there was a version before 1.0) and Win XP (released in 2001) . . . and that Task Scheduler 2.0 came out with Vista (released in 2007) . . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler

I have two machines . . . one with Win 8.1 (released in 2013), and the other with Win 10 (released in 2015) . . . I see that both of them have Task Scheduler 1.0

. . . This is 6 to 8 years after the release of Task Scheduler 2.0

I was having some problems getting Task Scheduler to run, so I thought, maybe there's a more current version of Task Scheduler out there, that's a separate update.

Also, I was thinking, why don't I at least have Task Scheduler version 2.0?

From clicking around, I learned that you cannot update the Task Scheduler in Windows, unless you upgrade to a newer version of Windows . . . (so why do Win 8.1 and Win 10 still only have Task Scheduler 1.0?).

This is apparently a bug, because I see on this page . . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler#Bugs . . . that the version was corrected to Task Scheduler 2.0 in Win 8:

"On Windows Vista, 7, 2008, and 2008 R2: The MMC Component says that you are running "Task Scheduler 1.0" when in fact you are running 2.0, this is a trivial bug so it wasn't noticed, and is likely due to the re-write of the task scheduler. The version has been corrected to 2.0 in Windows 8 and in 2012."

. . . so, why do both of my machines say that they're running Task Scheduler version 1.0?

They must be running Task Schedule 2.0 on them . . . Is there any way to verify this?

Comment: The build version of Task Schedule didn't change because they replaced a 1.0 version with a 1.0 version.  Only Wikipedia calls it "2.0"

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the most current Windows with all the updates applied, then you have the latest Task Scheduler.

From [the same Wikipedia link you provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler#Task_Scheduler_2.0):

"The redesigned Task Scheduler user interface is now based on Management Console.".

So if you're Task Scheduler is running in an MMC, then you have version 2.0 (or later, if they ever make one).

Answer (score 1):

When I open TS in Windows 10 and do a Help-About TS it shows version 1.0, I don't see this as a mistake. Wikipedia is not always correct.

[image]